# RackInitializationException after deploying Jruby war to Tomcat6

Tags: ruby-on-rails, tomcat, jruby, war

I am using:

```
jruby 1.7.2 (ruby-1.8.7p370)
Rails 2.0.2
jruby-jars-1.7.2
jruby-rack-1.1.13.1 
rake (10.0.3, 0.8.1) Rake 10.0.3 was installed by Warbler
```

I get the following error when I access the application:

```
org.jruby.rack.RackInitializationException: uninitialized constant Rack::Builder

from /usr/share/tomcat6/webapps/app/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activesupport-2.0.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:266:in `load_missing_constant'
from /usr/share/tomcat6/webapps/app/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activesupport-2.0.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:453:in `const_missing'
from null:1:in `(root)'
```

How can i solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a really old version of rails! :-) You should take it to the 2.3 branch if at all possible. I would be highly doubtful you won't have issues running it in jruby 1.7.1, as that runs as ruby 1.9 code. You might want to first dial it back to the last 1.6 version as it'll run in ruby 1.8.7 by default.

Also you may be too ambitious in using a newer tomcat. You should check out the trinidad gem as it may support you better on a legacy application.

However the gist of the issue is you're using a version of ruby that requires rack. Which I doubt you have in a rails app that is that old. IIRC it didn't come around until 2.2-ish.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions.I have installed the rack gem but i still get the error. Do you think there is a work around? or do i absolutely need to upgrade rails?

Comment: you probably just need to create a vanilla config.ru file in your root folder.

Comment: although given the seriousness of last weeks rails bug, I would upgrade to 2.3 latest :) If you can get it to 2.3.8 then you can iterate forward through the point releases fixing the deprecations as they're raised.